# Java code to find Upper and Lower number of each element in an array

Tags: arrays

I have an array `[22,30,32,36,40]`

I want to find nearest lower and upper value for each element. For ex. For 22 , lower value is 22 itself ani upper value is 30. For 30 , lower value is 22 and upper is 32. For 32 ,lower value is 30 and upper value is 36. For 36, lower is 32 and upper is 40.And for last element which is 40 ,lower value is 36 and upper is 40. 
Array becomes like `[ 22-30,22-32,30-36,32-40,36-40]`

Comment: What has this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: Sorry ...my mistake. It is related to array only,sir .

Answer (score 0):

Put the items into `TreeMap`. Then loop over the items in the original array and for each of them the `lowerKey()` in the `TreeMap` will be the predecessor and `higherKey()` its successor. If either of them was `null` it would mean it's already lowest/highest and you have to take the current element itself.

Comment: Can we perform this without using tree map?

Comment: @Ashwiniwaghamare : It definitely is possible for example by sorting the array and using binary search to find value and getting the left/right index. There are plenty of options generally. Or just completely unoptimized algorithm to always loop over the original array.

Comment: Vyskovsky : can you please elaborate how I can use binary search ?

Comment: @Ashwiniwaghamare : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)